# Creating Cart in Django using ManToManyField()

Tags: python, django

I have three classes in my Models and all have prices on them. I want to create Cart object. How do i pass all 3 in one CartItem using ManToManyField.

models.py

```
class Women(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    objects = models.manager

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Women'

class Men(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    objects = models.manager

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Men'


class Kids(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    objects = models.manager

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Kids'
```

I want to create

class Cart(models.Model):

and

class CartItem(models.Model):

Comment: Why do you make three models in the first place? Why not add a `type` field that can specify if it is `Men`/`Woman`/`Kids`?

Comment: I found it easy to pass them in my templates. My HTML is divided in three categories i.e the three models.

Comment: but the idea of a model-view-modelview structure, is exactly to *not* optimize models towards rendering. Models should be focused on storing data effectively. Views on retrieving data effectively, templates on rendering it effectively, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all three models have the same attributes, represent the same object, but it only change the "category" of the object, Why don't you create just one model with a category in which you choose the type? With that you will be able to scale to many other categories if necessary on the future:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    # add the choices:
    WOMEN = "W"
    MEN = 'M'
    KIDS = "K"
    SIGNED = "SI"
    TYPE = (
        (WOMEN, 'Women'),
        (MEN, 'Men'),
        (KIDS, 'Kids'),
    )
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='media')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    objects = models.manager
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TYPE, default=WOMEN, )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

With this code you will be able to sort all of the items by `type` to acquire each of your models as:

```
women_items = Item.objects.filter(type="W")  # women items
men_items = Item.objects.filter(type="M")  # women items
kids_items = Item.objects.filter(type="K")  # women items
```

Also for you to know, when you print the `type` attribute on templates like `{{item.type}}` you will get the text written on the `TYPE` list.

And this will make what you need much easier, so you will only need to refer to the `Item` model on the M2M relationship.

I'm not very related to shop carts but this might be what you are looking for:

```
class CartItem(models.Model):
    item = models.ManyToManyField(Item)
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

class Cart(models.Model):
    cart_item = models.ManyToManyField(CartItem)
```